# "Enable Area Descriptions" option of tango is not exist in my unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, tango

I follow this guide from Google:
https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-howto-area-learning
and appear about option "Enable Area Descriptions" in tango manager, but in my unity, is not appear in inspector, (verson 2017.1)
Someone knows why?

Comment: The last time I checked, Tango SDK was not working with Unity 2017+

Answer (score 0):

They have moved it to Tango Application (Script) -> Pose Mode  -> Local Area Description (Load Existing)

[image]